# Cancel task if "error" occurs in Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform 'AMForm' for students to choose their classes in high school.

There are adjacent option buttons for each class to select 'yes' or 'no' if they want to enroll in the class e.g. "Mechanical engineering" with 'yes' or 'no' option buttons next to it.

Once they submit their form I record the choices on the spreadsheet 'AMChoices'. This spreadsheet has each class in the above headings, so it fills the cell with 'x' if it has been selected e.g. if 'Mechanical Engineering' option button is selected it fills 'x' underneath this cell.

As the spreadsheet will host many users, it fills down to the next empty row to record each entry.

The Userform has restrictions such as not being able to choose specific classes together. I have error messages for this but when they click the "submit" button, even if there are errors, the choices are recorded.

How can I cancel the choices from being recorded until they are accepted?

In my code "optAMIB1" refers to "yes" option button for "Mechanical Engineering". There are lots of classes so there are several of these codes in my form, but I have just put in one for simplicity. Secondly, "txtAMS1" refers to a text box that automatically updates with the selected options' total credits e.g. Mech Eng is worth 20 credits, but they have to select enough classes to total 40.

```
Private Sub btnAMSubmit1_Click()

 Dim Total As String
 Dim Total2 As String
 Dim CurrentCell As Range
 Dim AMChoiceSht As Worksheet
 Dim LastRow As Long

 'Semester 1 Credits
 Total = 0

 ' set the worksheet object
 Set AMChoiceSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AMChoices")

 'Choose IB1 Sem 1
 With AMChoiceSht
  LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row ' find last row in column B
  Set CurrentCell = .Range("F" & LastRow + 1) ' set the range of next empty row
 End With

 If Me.optAMIB1 Then
  Total = Total + 20
  CurrentCell.Value2 = "X"
 End If

 If Me.optAMIB1 = False Then
  CurrentCell.Value2 = "-"
 End If

 'add up to 40
 If Me.txtAMS1 <> 40 Then
  MsgBox "Error. Semester One Credits must be equal to 40."
 End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not ideal, but has saved me in the past... After each msbox line, write a new line:

```
err = 1
```

Then before you push the data to the sheet:

```
if err = 0 then 
    'push data to the spreadsheet
    unload me
else
    'nothing
end if
```

---

I have utilized this to prevent data submission in the past, where I have many separate switches or statements for utilizing data/buttons.

Note you need to define err for your option explicit module.  Inherently, err = 0, when Dim err as Long, though you may want to specify err = 0 before you start the rest of your subroutine.

This should allow you to put out all msgbox from different checks, then keep the sheet up.

Comment: Adding a comment to my own post... Excel is not a database, and does not inherently allow queuing for data entry.  if something prevents entry to the workbook, then nothing while the error is being displayed will be input either.  I would recommend using an actual database which is built for handing data submission.

Comment: Will make another recommendation...  Save a string instead of populating a msgbox per pre-determined issue (where you shouldn't be able to pair certain classes).  Then append all strings together in one msgbox and display.  Similar to your total = total  + 20, you can use errstr = errstr & "  " & "More text here." to keep things in one line, then MsgBox(errstr)

Comment: Just to clarify - do I put this under the "err" function under each option button code or only under the error code message box?

Comment: You are trying to catch where errors occur, so if you have an error and are displaying a msgbox, then you want the line AFTER the msgbox (inside of any if statement, etc.) to be err=1, that way you have captured the error and will prevent submission of data.